# iOS Fire local notification every day on specific time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to fire a local notification every day on 12:01 AM , but I don't know why my code does not work. Would you please help me to find the problem?

```
local = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSPersianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

//edited:
[dateComps setYear:1390]; //2012
[dateComps setMonth:10]; //1
[dateComps setDay:9];    //29

 local.repeatInterval = 5;

[dateComps setHour:00];
[dateComps setMinute:1];
[dateComps setSecond:00];


local.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
local.alertBody = @"HELLO";
local.alertAction = @"View";
local.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:local];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting the notification's `repeatInterval` property and your date components are missing a month, year and day. The defaults are zero, so your `fireDate` is way back in the past.

Also, you might want to be using `NSGregorianCalendar` instead of `NSPersianCalendar`.

Comment: because the date and time is based on Persian calendar , so I should declare NSPersianCalendar for my dates , I also added year , day and month and `repeatInterval`  would you please see my edited code :

Comment: The `repeatInterval` should be an `NSCalendarUnit`, such as `NSDayCalendarUnit`, not an integer. Also, you might need to set the notification's `repeatCalendar` since you're working with the Persian calendar (I don't have any experience with this though).

Comment: Would you please write an example code for NSGregorianCalendar ? then I can convert it to the persian ,